# Is there a way to extract the selected text into a new file in the same directory?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text, is there a way I can extract a selected piece of text into a separate file?

I do this often in LaTeX. Consider the following file:

main.tex

```
\section{Introduction}
...
...

\section{Conclusion}
```

I want to be able to select the text starting from `Introduction` until one line before the `Conclusion`, right-click and then say "Extract to file" (somewhat similar to how "Extract method" works in Visual Studio). Is there a way to achieve this using any shortcuts?

**Bonus**: Once the extraction is complete, substitute the extracted text with custom text such as `\input{introduction}` where `introduction` is the name of the file that the text was extracted into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built in, but it's easily doable with a plugin. Note the following is minimally tested and won't handle everything in ST well. That being said, it should be a good base for you to start with. Just to be safe, I'd throw everything into a local git repo before using this to much. Hate for this to lead to loss of work. I copy the content being replaced to the clipboard just to be safe, but if you feel confident with it, you can remove `sublime.set_clipboard(content)`

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os
import re

class ExtractAndInput(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        self.region = view.sel()[0]
        content = view.substr(self.region)
        sublime.set_clipboard(content)
        match = re.search(r"\\section{(.+?)}", content)
        if match:
            replace = "\\input{%s}" % match.group(1)
            view.replace(edit, view.sel()[0], replace)
            current = view.file_name()
            new_file = "%s.tex" % match.group(1)
            path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(current, "..", new_file))
            with open(path, "a") as file_obj:
                file_obj.write("% Generated using ExtractAndInput Plugin\n")
                file_obj.write(content)
```

After saving the plugin, you can create a key binding to `extract_and_input`. You can also add a context menu by creating a `Context.sublime-menu` in `Packages/User` with the following content.

```
[
    { "caption": "Extract to File", "command": "extract_and_input"}
]
```